# A Cache Efficient Matrix Transpose Program?

Tags: algorithm, caching, matrix

So the obvious way to transpose a matrix is to use :

```
  for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )

    for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )

      destination[j+i*n] = source[i+j*n];
```

but I want something that will take advantage of locality and cache blocking. I was looking it up and can't find code that would do this, but I'm told it should be a very simple modification to the original. Any ideas?

Edit: I have a 2000x2000 matrix, and I want to know how can I change the code using two `for` loops, basically splitting the matrix into blocks that I transpose individually, say 2x2 blocks, or 40x40 blocks, and see which block size is most efficient.

Edit2: The matrices are stored in column major order, that is to say for a matrix

```
a1 a2    
a3 a4
```

is stored as `a1 a3 a2 a4`.

Comment: Beware because a really hot modern coompiler might well sort this out for you by using powerful optimisations that completely redesign the code. Check out the keyword restrict. Take a look at all optimisation switches eg for gcc for example must start with using -O3 or -O2, whichever is fastest, and also *must* use switches to enable support for your modern cpu's full instruction set eg for gcc -march=haswell. Don't use crap compilers. Gcc the Intel ones and llvm/clang all are good.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You're probably going to want four loops - two to iterate over the blocks, and then another two to perform the transpose-copy of a single block. Assuming for simplicity a block size that divides the size of the matrix, something like this I think, although I'd want to draw some pictures on the backs of envelopes to be sure:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += blocksize) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j += blocksize) {
        // transpose the block beginning at [i,j]
        for (int k = i; k < i + blocksize; ++k) {
            for (int l = j; l < j + blocksize; ++l) {
                dst[k + l*n] = src[l + k*n];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An important further insight is that there's actually a cache-oblivious algorithm for this (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm, which uses this exact problem as an example). The informal definition of "cache-oblivious" is that you don't need to experiment tweaking any parameters (in this case the blocksize) in order to hit good/optimal cache performance. The solution in this case is to transpose by recursively dividing the matrix in half, and transposing the halves into their correct position in the destination.

Whatever the cache size actually is, this recursion takes advantage of it. I expect there's a bit of extra management overhead compared with your strategy, which is to use performance experiments to, in effect, jump straight to the point in the recursion at which the cache really kicks in, and go no further. On the other hand, your performance experiments might give you an answer that works on your machine but not on your customers' machines.

Comment: So if we have a 7 by 7 matrix with a blocksize of 2 will this code break, edge-case wise?

Comment: @user635832: yes it will, because the bounds on `k` and `l` are `i+2` and `j+2`, which for the blocks all around the right-bottom edges will overrun the actual matrix by a margin of 1 because `i` or `j` will be 6. Simplest fix is to bound `k` by `k < i+blocksize && k < n`, and the same for `l`. Unless I've missed something or messed it up - I haven't tested this code at all.

Comment: It's weird, I was testing this code, and it seems to work, but actually runs slower with the cache efficiency then without. Maybe 2000x2000 matrices are too small for the efficiency gain?

Comment: @user63582: You don't say the type of the matrix, but at 16MB a good proportion of the matrix fits in L3 cache on a typical intel-based machine, so yes, could be too small. Or maybe I've got it wrong, and this block-wise transposition isn't that great for cache. I think it should be, with a blocksize of around 64 bytes squared, but I may be confused or it may be the compiler does a good enough job with the original code and memory pre-fetching. Are you at max optimization, and do you have a profiler on that counts cache misses, to prove whether it's actually cache-efficient or not?

Comment: @Steve It seems that once I get to 8000x8000 matrix the efficiency for naive solution becomes slower than the cache efficient one. Edit: I don't have a profiler yet. I might be able to set one up.

Comment: Oh, and if this is implemented as a function, have you marked the pointer parameters `src` and `dst` as `restrict`? If you have then at least in principle, the compiler can re-order the copies for itself in ways that it can't do when there's a possibility that `src` and `dst` overlap. Chances are, it knows more about your hardware than you do.

Comment: Correction: I think there was some problem compiling. The solution you provided is 4 times faster :)

Comment: @SteveJessop, I got a big speed up using your suggestion along with SSE.  I posted my results here (see the end of my answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737298/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-transpose-a-matrix-in-c/16743203#16743203 Thank You!

Comment: Why is this faster than a naive transpose? From what i've learnt about caches (in the last 3 days so please be nice), the destination write should be happening in the cache (in the naive algorithm), whereas the read access cannot be in the cache (since we're accessing it in steps of n, unless n < blocksize). Whether we're in the optimized case or the naive case, we're stepping through only one of the two matrices in offsets of 1 (which will use the cache due to spatial locality), the other matrix in both cases will be accessed in steps of n, which will result in a cache miss everytime. Right?

Comment: @user2635088: hard to explain this without waving my arms around, but the trick is that on whichever side you're making steps of n, you want to provoke m cache misses, where m\*n fits in cache. Then, you go back to where you started, shuffle over one place, and do another m steps of n, which now *will not* provoke cache misses on that side, because they're all adjacent to the stuff you just cached. So the goal is to get m small enough. You can do this by manually choosing it, or you can use the cache-oblivious algorithm which ensures that most of the work is done using small m.

Comment: @Steve I think the input matrix has to be also in the right dimensions, if not than your blocks might be actually in different cache lines.

Comment: Can you please explain how does this work with the dst matrix? Because you are writing in column order so the reading of the blocks is cache friendly but writing to the dst matrix isn't... yet it still is a lot faster than the naive solution

Answer (score 15):

I had the exact same problem yesterday.
I ended up with this solution:

```
void transpose(double *dst, const double *src, size_t n, size_t p) noexcept {
    THROWS();
    size_t block = 32;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i += block) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < p; ++j) {
            for(size_t b = 0; b < block && i + b < n; ++b) {
                dst[j*n + i + b] = src[(i + b)*p + j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is 4 time faster than the obvious solution on my machine.**

This solution takes care of a rectangular matrix with dimensions which are not a multiple of the block size.

if dst and src are the same square matrix an in place function should really be used instead:

```
void transpose(double*m,size_t n)noexcept{
    size_t block=0,size=8;
    for(block=0;block+size-1<n;block+=size){
        for(size_t i=block;i<block+size;++i){
            for(size_t j=i+1;j<block+size;++j){
                std::swap(m[i*n+j],m[j*n+i]);}}
        for(size_t i=block+size;i<n;++i){
            for(size_t j=block;j<block+size;++j){
                std::swap(m[i*n+j],m[j*n+i]);}}}
    for(size_t i=block;i<n;++i){
        for(size_t j=i+1;j<n;++j){
            std::swap(m[i*n+j],m[j*n+i]);}}}
```

I used C++11 but this could be easily translated in other languages.

Comment: In the first function where do you use "p"?

Comment: Should this line "dst[j*n + i + b] = src[(i + b)*n + j];" remain unchaged?

Comment: @Lingviston You were absolutely correct again. I fixed the line.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of transposing the matrix in memory, why not collapse the transposition operation into the next operation you're going to do on the matrix?

Comment: Definitely worth considering.  One nice way is to make an object that presents a "view" over the original matrix, like a view in a database.

Comment: More than simply worth considering, @j_random_hacker. A "view" object in the short run decouples representation from intent, which is generally a good design strategy. It also allows you to build towards letting the computer figure out good algorithms for things in a manner similar to what a database query optimizers do.

Comment: This is good advice. A very minor performance warning: Implementing views might well end up with introducing calls through function pointers rather than calls to known fixed function addresses. Calling through unknown variable pointers can be very slow on some modern machines.

Answer (score 7):

Steve Jessop mentioned a cache oblivious matrix transpose algorithm.
For the record, I want to share an possible implementation of a cache oblivious matrix transpose.

```
public class Matrix {
    protected double data[];
    protected int rows, columns;

    public Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.data = new double[rows * columns];
    }

    public Matrix transpose() {
        Matrix C = new Matrix(columns, rows);
        cachetranspose(0, rows, 0, columns, C);
        return C;
    }

    public void cachetranspose(int rb, int re, int cb, int ce, Matrix T) {
        int r = re - rb, c = ce - cb;
        if (r <= 16 && c <= 16) {
            for (int i = rb; i < re; i++) {
                for (int j = cb; j < ce; j++) {
                    T.data[j * rows + i] = data[i * columns + j];
                }
            }
        } else if (r >= c) {
            cachetranspose(rb, rb + (r / 2), cb, ce, T);
            cachetranspose(rb + (r / 2), re, cb, ce, T);
        } else {
            cachetranspose(rb, re, cb, cb + (c / 2), T);
            cachetranspose(rb, re, cb + (c / 2), ce, T);
        }
    }
}
```

More details on cache oblivious algorithms can be found [here](http://wgropp.cs.illinois.edu/courses/cs598-s16/lectures/lecture08.pdf).

Comment: The link for additional information results in a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the broken link.

Comment: Link broken again.

Answer (score 3):

[Matrix multiplication](http://lwn.net/Articles/255364/) comes to mind, but the cache issue there is much more pronounced, because each element is read *N* times.

With matrix transpose, you are reading in a single linear pass and there's no way to optimize that. But you can simultaneously process several rows so that you write several columns and so fill complete cache lines. You will only need three loops.

Or do it the other way around and read in columns while writing linearly.

Comment: Good advice indeed. I'm not sure which way round is fastest, depends on machine architecture.

Answer (score 0):

With a large matrix, possibly a large sparse matrix, it might be an idea to decompose it into smaller cache friendly chunks (Say, 4x4 sub matrices). You can also flag sub matrices as identity which will help you in creating optimized code paths.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample C++ code for cache friendly parallelized matrix transposition:

```
constexpr auto range(unsigned max) 
    { return std::views::iota(0u, max); }
constexpr auto range(unsigned start, unsigned max) 
    { return std::views::iota(start, max); }

constexpr auto SZ = 1000u;
std::array<std::array<int, SZ>, SZ> mx;

void testtranspose(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SZ; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < SZ; j++)
            mx[i][j] = j;

    // ***************
    //       cache friendly in place parallel transposition
    constexpr unsigned block_size = 10; assert(SZ % block_size == 0);
    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq,
        range(SZ / block_size).begin(), range(SZ / block_size).end(), 
        [&](const unsigned iib)
        {   //cache friendly transposition
            const unsigned ii = iib * block_size;
            //transpose the diagonal block
            for (unsigned i = ii; i < ii + block_size; i++)
                for (unsigned j = i + 1; j < ii + block_size; j++)
                    std::swap(mx[i][j], mx[j][i]);
            //transpose the rest of blocks
            for (unsigned jj = ii + block_size; jj < SZ; jj += block_size)
                for (unsigned i = ii; i < ii + block_size; i++)
                    for (unsigned j = jj; j < jj + block_size; j++)
                        std::swap(mx[i][j], mx[j][i]);
        });
    // ***************

    for (int i = 0; i < SZ; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < SZ; j++)
            assert(mx[i][j] == i);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).