# Algorithm to optimize nested loops

Tags: algorithm, for-loop

Is there an algorithm available to optimize the performance of the following?

```
for (i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < LIMIT; j++) {
   // do something with i and j
  }
 }
```

- Both `i` and `j` start at 0
- Both loops end on the same condition
- Both `i` and `j` are incremented at the same rate

Can this be done in 1 loop somehow?

Comment: Why do you want to optimize this?  The loops are perfectly fine as-is.

Comment: *Both `i` and `j` are incremented at the same rate* - no. `j` gets incremented `LIMIT` times as often, if *by the same increment*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It *is* possible to write this using one loop, but I would strongly suggest not doing so.  The double for-loop is a well-established idiom that programmers know how to read, and if you collapse the two loops into one you sacrifice readability.  Moreover, it's unclear if this will actually make the code run any faster, since the compiler is already very good at optimizing loops.  Collapsing the two loops into one requires some extra math at each step that is almost certainly slower than the two loops independently.

That said, if you do want to write this as a single loop, one idea is to think about the **iteration space**, the set of pairs that you iterate over.  Right now, that looks like this:

```
(0, 0)   (0, 1),   (0, 2), ...,   (0, N-1)
(1, 0)   (1, 1),   (1, 2), ...,   (1, N-1)
                ...          
(N-1, 0) (N-1, 1), (N-1, 2), ..., (N-1, N-1)
```

The idea is to try to visit all of these pairs in the order `(0, 0), (0, 1), ..., (0, N-1), (1, 0), (1, 1), ..., (1, N-1), ..., (N-1, 0), (N-1, 1), ..., (N-1, N-1)`.  To do this, note that every time we increment `i`, we skip over `N` elements, while when we increment `j` we skip over just one element.  Consequently, iteration `(i, j)` of the loop will map to position `i * N + j` in the linearized loop ordering.  This means that on iteration `i * N + j`, we want to visit `(i, j)`.  To do this, we can recover `i` and `j` from the index using some simple arithmetic.  If `k` is the current loop counter, we want to visit

```
i = k / N   (integer division)
j = k % N
```

Thus the loop can be written as

```
for (int k = 0; k < N * N; ++k) {
    int i = k / N;
    int j = k % N;
}
```

However, you have to be careful with this because `N * N` might not fit into an integer and thus could overflow.  In that case, you would want to fall back on the double for-loop.  Moreover, the introduction of the extra divisions and moduli will make this code run (potentially) much slower than the double for-loop.  Finally, this code is much harder to read than the original code, and you'd need to be sure to provide aggressive comments describing what it is that you're doing here.  Again, I strongly advise you not to do this at all unless you have a very strong reason to suspect that there is a problem with the standard double for-loop.

(Interestingly, the trick used here can also be used to represent a multidimensional array using a single-dimensional array.  The logic is identical - you have a two-dimensional structure that you want to represent with a one-dimensional structure.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: hmm does using post- and pre-increments help? ie.  element[i++]=element[++j]?

Comment: It's worth noting that modulo can be orders of magnitude slower than bitmasking by a power of two.  (Though the compiler will likely do this under the hood if it can guarantee that N is a power of two.)  Division can similarly be replaced with a bitshift, though it isn't much faster (if at all).

Comment: Interesting comment about using nested for-loops as providing better readability and context for other developers. I guess there's always a trade off between optimization and readability, and sometimes, perhaps for inexpensive operations (small data sets etc), nested for-loops are just fine. All this time I keep thinking using them is bad practice if I can optimize...

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to significantly optimize the loop itself. However, when you consider the details of "do something with i and j", it can make a big difference whether i or j is the outer loop. For example, one order may cause jumping around a lot in memory or disk while the other order results in sequential access, or nearly so.

Also, you can optimize a double loop sometimes by moving computations that don't rely on the inner index from the inner to the outer loop, maybe with a temporary variable. Smart compilers may optimize this to a point, but they're not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You can't improve the big-O performance of the loop. However, there are algorithm-dependent methods of improving the constant factor hidden by the big-O by taking advantage of the cache.

Here is an example of an improved matrix transpose algorithm: [A Cache Efficient Matrix Transpose Program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200338/a-cache-efficient-matrix-transpose-program)

However the common theme here is that we actually introduce **more** loops, rather than fewer.

Answer (score 1):

If you must speed up the for loop at any price, see if you can find a parallelising or vectorising compiler and modify it as required to get it to take advantage of that, or find a way to use some library of building blocks. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_Compiler and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library.

(Or find a better algorithm - frequently that will give you something like the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
  // Do something clever with i 
  // that does not depend on j
  for (j = 0; j < LIMIT; j++) {
    // do something fast with i and j
    // and the results of the clever stuff
    // outside the loop over j
  }
}
```

)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you need both i and j within the inner loop, e.g. sometimes you can *flatten* such a loop like this:

```
for (k = 0; k < LIMIT * LIMIT; ++k)
{
    // do something with k
}
```

but for all but the most trivial inner loops it probably makes no perceivable difference to performance.

What specific problem are you actually trying to solve ?

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same issue a while ago...

What do you think about this? Single while loop (i is the index of the outter for-loop in your example):

```
i = 0; j = 0;
while (i<M) {
  // Do something with i and j
  if (j<N-1) {
    j++;
  } else {
    j=0;
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be a long whlie back but isn't this of the same complexity as double `for` loop? I think here you will iterate `N-1` times forearch `i`. OP said he had same length for both, so it would be `j<M` so you would actually iterate M*M times which is O(n2) I believe? Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm trying to get my head around algorithmics :p