# Kth sum in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, search, sum, binary-search

I have an array  with n elements ,i need to calculate all n*n  sum of pair of two elements  (array[i]+array[j]).All sums are arranged in ascending order.I need to find Kth sum

for example:

array[] = {3,4,5}

all sums: {(3+3),(3+4),(4+3),(3+5),(5+3),(4+4),(4+5),(5+4),(5+5)}

K = 6

I need to find value for Kth sum ( in this case 6th sum is 4+4 ,i will return 8);

Solution might be very optimal

---

this is my solution; it isn't optimal:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    fin>>a[i];
qsort(a, n, sizeof(int), int_cmp);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=i;j<n;j++)
            {
                sum[k]=a[i]+a[j];
                if(i!=j)
                    sum[++k]=a[i]+a[j];
                k++;
                }
qsort(sum, n*n, sizeof(int), int_cmp);
cout<<sum[nrs-1];
```

Comment: So what's the problem? What code have you written?

Comment: i need an idea to implement this .I've implemented that ,but is inefficiently

Comment: If you posted the code maybe we could help you improve it. I don't know if anyone on this site will take the time to write it for you, although it doesn't seem very difficult.

Comment: I solved that problem ,but inefficiently .I need an idea for that

Comment: i don't need an implemntation .I want an idea or an simple algorithm

Comment: I think I would start off by looping through the arrays and calculating the sums and putting the results into another array. Then sort the results array in ascending order. After that, it's easy to get the kth sum by just simply pointing to the kth element in the results array.

Comment: this is same with my code :)) if i give an array with 10000 elements it's not working

Comment: Well that is the most direct approach. I suspected you probably did it that way ;) but you didn't say.

Comment: i put my code :)  in description

Comment: Have you figured out which piece takes the longest? Have you tried `std::sort` instead? Could you run the operations (like more than one `qsort`, split up over the results array) in parallel?

Comment: I don't tried std::sort   'cause  I don't no to use STL ,and advanced C++,

Comment: i think this approaching isn't well.  I want a new  idea for that,seems like binary search

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar kind of question from google interview question in that they use two sorted array instead of one but the solution works.One optimization which will work in `O(klogk)` can be given here. 
To find the maximum value in such a case it is necessary to have calculated all the values lesser than it,ie let `i,j` be the maximum values in your case `5,5` to consider `5,5` to be max it is necessary to have evaluated both `4,5`and `5,4`.that is `i-1,j` and `i,j-1` So a working code will be to use a `heap` in c++ it is a `priority queue`. The code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <queue>  

using namespace std;   
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
fin>>a[i];
qsort(a, n, sizeof(int), int_cmp);
std::priority_queue<int > heap;


heap.add(pair(n-1, n-1));  // biggest pair n=array size

// remove max k-1 times 
for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; ++i) {
// get max and remove it from the heap
max = heap.pop();

// add next candidates
heap.push(pair(max.i - 1, max.j));
heap.push(pair(max.i, max.j - 1));
}

// get k-th maximum element
max = heap.pop();
maxVal = a[max.i] + a[max.j];
```

Now this one is optimized upto `O(k.logk)` there is another one which gives `O(k)`.You can find it here.[Kth sum in O(k)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557175/how-to-find-pair-with-kth-largest-sum)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this idea .But i still have a problem .I have some errors :
 1) error: no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::greater<int>' 
2)error: template argument 3 is invalid|
I think i have to add a library or something

Comment: I have added the necessary modifications in the code. It is a thing about library or rather STL