# Find the k-th sum from sums of every pair

Tags: algorithm, sequences

I'm given the array with n elements and I need to find k-th sum from sums of every pair n^2 in time complexity O(n*logn), sums are in ascending order.

---

Example input

In the first line are given number of elements and number of sum to find. In the second line list of number which sums of pair we need to generate.

```
 3 6
 1 4 6
```

---

The answer is 8 for given list, below is array of every pair of sums, where 8, sum of 4+4 is on the 6-th position.

```
2 5 5 7 7 8 10 10 12
```

where first three elements are genereted as follow

- 1+1 = 2
- 1+4 = 5
- 4+1 = 5

Edit: 
I came up to this that the main problem is to find place for sum of elements with themselves. I will give example to make it more clear.

For sequence [1, 4, 10], we have

```
2 5 5 8 11 11 14 14 20
```

The problem is where to place sum of 4+4, that depends if 1+10 > 4+4, others sums  have fixed place because second element + last will be always bigger than last + first (if we have elements in ascending order).

Comment: I didn't understand the question. What is k here in the input? Please write a clear description of the problem.

Comment: Please clarify the problem statement. What is the order of the pair sums? Is there a canonical order, or are the sums sorted by increasing value, or something else?

Comment: @SomeDude - As I understand it, OP wants to generate a list sums of two elements from the input array and then find the k-th element of that list.

Comment: The problem is tricky. Since there are n^2 pair sums, it's possible that k > n * log n. Therefore any O(n*log n) algorithm cannot rely on enumerating the first k pair sums. I don't know if there is a solution.

Comment: @Piotr how do you know that a solution exists?

Comment: @fafl this is task from site with alogirthms challenges and it have a restriction n <= 250 000 so complexity O(n^2) gives timeout. There are already accepted submission for it.

Comment: You shouldn't post questions for active algorithm challenges!!

Comment: @Amit this task is not in active challenge, it is only for training purpose.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557175/how-to-find-pair-with-kth-largest-sum

Comment: @juvian this doesn't quit work for this because k <= n^2, which gives k^2 log(k^2) complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to juvian solving the hard parts, I was able to write this solution, the comments should explain it:

```py
def count_sums_of_at_most(amount, nums1, nums2):

    p1 = 0  # Pointer into the first array, start at the beginning
    p2 = len(nums2) - 1  # Pointer into the second array, start at the end

    # Move p1 up and p2 down, walking through the "diagonal" in O(n)
    sum_count = 0
    while p1 < len(nums1):
        while amount < nums1[p1] + nums2[p2]:
            p2 -= 1
            if p2 < 0:
                # p1 became too large, we are done
                break
        else:
            # Found a valid p2 for the given p1
            sum_count += p2 + 1
            p1 += 1
            continue
        break

    return sum_count

def find_sum(k, nums1, nums2):

    # Sort both arrays, this runs in O(n * log(n))
    nums1.sort()
    nums2.sort()

    # Binary search through all sums, runs in O(n * log(max_sum))
    low = nums1[0] + nums2[0]
    high = nums1[-1] + nums2[-1]
    while low <= high:
        mid = (high + low) // 2
        sum_count = count_sums_of_at_most(mid, nums1, nums2)
        if sum_count >= k:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1

    return low

arr = [1, 4, 5, 6]
for k in range(1, 1 + len(arr) ** 2):
    print('sum', k, 'is', find_sum(k, arr, arr))
```

This prints:

```
sum 1 is 2
sum 2 is 5
sum 3 is 5
sum 4 is 6
sum 5 is 6
sum 6 is 7
sum 7 is 7
sum 8 is 8
sum 9 is 9
sum 10 is 9
sum 11 is 10
sum 12 is 10
sum 13 is 10
sum 14 is 11
sum 15 is 11
sum 16 is 12
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved in O(n log maxSum).

Pseudocode:

```
sort(array)
low = array[1] * 2
high = array[n] * 2
while (low <= high): (binarySearch between low and high)
    mid = floor((high + low) / 2)
    qty = checkHowManySumsAreEqualOrLessThan(mid)
    if qty >= k:
        high = mid - 1
    else:
        low = mid + 1
answer = low // low will be the first value of mid where qty was >= k. This means that on low - 1, qty was < k. This means the solution must be low
```

Sorting is O(n log n). Binary search costs log(array[n] * 2 - array[0] * 2).

checkHowManySumsAreEqualOrLessThan(mid) can be done in O(n) using 2 pointers, let me know if you can't figure out how.

This works because even though we are not doing the binary search over k, it is true that if there were x sums <= mid, if k < x then the kth sum would be lower than mid. Same for when k > x.

Comment: Can you explain function `checkHowManySumsAreEqualOrLessThan` in more details?

Comment: This does not work. `mid` will have `k` sums that are equal or less, but there is no guarantee that `mid` is one of the sums.

Comment: @fafl you are right, should have tried coding it but was busy at the time. If qty is equal to k, it is true that the highest number you can sum less or equal to mid will be the answer. As there can be repeated sums, it could happen that it never happens that qty is equal to k, in that case the binary search will end with low equal to high and the result will be that +-1.

Comment: @fafl fixed the binary search, you can save some lines on your code with this fix ^^

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this is O(n^2)

The way I understood the problem, the first number on the first row is the number of numbers, and the second number is k.

You can do this problem by using a PriorityQueue, which orders everything for you as you input numbers. Use 2 nested for loops such that they visit each pair once.

```
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= k; j++){
```

If j==k, enter k+j into the PriorityQueue once, if not, enter the sum twice. Then, loop through the PriorityQueue to get he 6th value.

Will edit with full code if you'd like.

Comment: I believe that your nested `for` loops will execute in O(n^2) time. OP needs an O(n*log n) algorithm.

Comment: This have a time complexity O(n^2), because inner loop runs 1+2+..n = (n*(n+1))/2 times.