# How to generate a sequence of indexes of a nested loop that has cache locality?

Tags: python, c, cpu-cache, gray-code

Imagine you have two arrays and you want to iterate a nested loop of them, such as the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int sizes[5] = {4, 4};
  for (int i = 0 ; i < sizes[0]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < sizes[1]; j++) {
      printf("%d%d\n", i, j);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This produces the following pattern of indexes. The first number of each line is i and the second number is j.

```
00
01
02
03
10
11
12
13
20
21
22
23
30
31
32
33
```

The problem with this pattern is that it is bad for caches. The cache for j gets blown repeatedly. From a cache perspective all the data from 0-4 is loaded into the caches and thrown away before being cycled again on the next loop of i. I don't want the indexes to go back to 0, here is a similar sequence I want to produce:

```
00
10
30
20
21
31
11
01
03
13
33
23
22
32
12
02
```

Notice that each index doesn't repeat in a cycle. The indexes don't cycle. The indexes are all within 2 positions with eachother, so the cache line of memory can be used.

I produced this sequence with a [reflected binary code or a gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code), inspired by [this Hacker News comment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=32191251)

Here is the code I used to produce this sequence:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 4, 8, 16]
indexes = set()
correct = set()

print("graycode loop indexes")
for index in range(0, len(a) * len(b)):
  code = index ^ (index >> 1)
  left = code & 0x0003
  right = code >> 0x0002 & 0x0003

  print("{}{}".format(left, right))
  indexes.add((left, right))

assert len(indexes) == 16

print("regular nested loop indexes")

for x in range(0, len(a)):
  for y in range(0, len(b)):
    correct.add((x,y))
    print("{}{}".format(x, y))


assert correct == indexes
```

**How do I generalize this sequence for varied length arrays?**

For example, Imagine I have 3 lists of size 5, 8, 16 respectively, I want to iterate those lists in a nested loop but not blow the cache. I want to visit every index with as much in the cache as I can.

Said another way, for each I I want to go through every J but I want to do so in a sequence that does not result in repeating J.

Comment: Gray code can grantee that only 1 bit is changed between adjacent element, but flipping high digit results in jumping the location to access, which may be bad for the cache. I think zig-zag ordering like `00 01 10 20 11 02 03 12 21 30 ...` is better.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post your real code. The actual usage can dictate the solution. Your first example _is_ cache friendly assuming the size of the array you're trying to access is less than the size of the cache on your system. Your array (_not_ `sizes`) is (e.g.) `int array[4][4];` That is, `j` is the column index. If the array is large/huge, you can access it in smaller blocks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200338/a-cache-efficient-matrix-transpose-program Access via gray codes is semi-random [in effect]. So, either don't worry or do what the link suggests

Comment: Craig, Thank you for your comment, I appreciate it. This is largely a thought puzzle that I find interesting in trying to find a solution. I want to maximize use of what is in the cache at any given point for ridiculously large matrixes. Thank you for the link. I don't actually have any code to optimise as I am yet to write it. I am sure that might be the wrong approach to take but I find optimisation stuff interesting.

Comment: Okay. I'd do this access in C. You can measure this, at least to see the speedup. It would be more difficult in python due to the language's overhead. C has _true_ 2D arrays. AFAIK, python can only do a 2D array by having a 1D "row" vector that has pointers/references to 1D arrays of numbers. With `T = [[11, 12, 5], [15, 6,10], [10, 8, 12], [12,15,6]]`, in C, this is: `int *T[4];` rather than: `int T[4][3];` So, you're already at a significant disadvantage. If you want to use this in python, I'd create a binding to the C code and have the C code do the matrix operations.

Comment: I plan to do this in C or Rust. I was doing the calculation in python for easiness (I tend to prototype in python and then rewrite in C or Java)

Answer (score 0):

It seems cache lines work with backwards and forwards locality. Jumping around memory randomly is inefficient but spatially local is efficient.

I produce indexes that maximize the use of what is in the cache line by iterating in reverse directions, alternating as the loop goes on.

This ensures the data at the index positions should be near eachother on the cache line.

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
c = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

efficient = set()
correct = set()
alternating = [False, False, False]
for i in range(0, len(a)):
  for j in range(0, len(b)):
    for k in range(0, len(c)):
      correct.add((i, j, k))

 
for i in range(0, len(a)):
  if alternating[1]:
    jstart = (len(b) - 1)
    jend = -1
    jstep = -1
  else:
    jstart = 0
    jend = len(b)
    jstep = 1
  for j in range(jstart, jend, jstep):
    if alternating[2]:
      kstart = (len(c) -1)
      kend = -1
      kstep = -1
    else:
      kstart = 0
      kend = len(c)
      kstep = 1
    for k in range(kstart, kend, kstep):
      
      new_item = (i, j, k)
      print(tuple(new_item))
      efficient.add(new_item)
    alternating[2] = not alternating[2]
  alternating[1] = True

print(len(correct))

print(len(efficient))



print("missing")
print(correct - efficient)
print("surplus")
print(efficient - correct)
assert correct == efficient
```

This produces the following indexes:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 4)
(0, 1, 4)
(0, 1, 3)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 2, 0)
(0, 2, 1)
(0, 2, 2)
(0, 2, 3)
(0, 2, 4)
(0, 3, 4)
(0, 3, 3)
(0, 3, 2)
(0, 3, 1)
(0, 3, 0)
(0, 4, 0)
(0, 4, 1)
(0, 4, 2)
(0, 4, 3)
(0, 4, 4)
(1, 4, 4)
(1, 4, 3)
(1, 4, 2)
(1, 4, 1)
(1, 4, 0)
(1, 3, 0)
(1, 3, 1)
(1, 3, 2)
(1, 3, 3)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 0)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 4)
(1, 0, 4)
(1, 0, 3)
(1, 0, 2)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(2, 4, 0)
(2, 4, 1)
(2, 4, 2)
(2, 4, 3)
(2, 4, 4)
(2, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 3)
(2, 3, 2)
(2, 3, 1)
(2, 3, 0)
(2, 2, 0)
(2, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 3)
(2, 2, 4)
(2, 1, 4)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 1, 2)
(2, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 0)
(2, 0, 0)
(2, 0, 1)
(2, 0, 2)
(2, 0, 3)
(2, 0, 4)
(3, 4, 4)
(3, 4, 3)
(3, 4, 2)
(3, 4, 1)
(3, 4, 0)
(3, 3, 0)
(3, 3, 1)
(3, 3, 2)
(3, 3, 3)
(3, 3, 4)
(3, 2, 4)
(3, 2, 3)
(3, 2, 2)
(3, 2, 1)
(3, 2, 0)
(3, 1, 0)
(3, 1, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 1, 3)
(3, 1, 4)
(3, 0, 4)
(3, 0, 3)
(3, 0, 2)
(3, 0, 1)
(3, 0, 0)
(4, 4, 0)
(4, 4, 1)
(4, 4, 2)
(4, 4, 3)
(4, 4, 4)
(4, 3, 4)
(4, 3, 3)
(4, 3, 2)
(4, 3, 1)
(4, 3, 0)
(4, 2, 0)
(4, 2, 1)
(4, 2, 2)
(4, 2, 3)
(4, 2, 4)
(4, 1, 4)
(4, 1, 3)
(4, 1, 2)
(4, 1, 1)
(4, 1, 0)
(4, 0, 0)
(4, 0, 1)
(4, 0, 2)
(4, 0, 3)
(4, 0, 4)
125
125
missing
set()
surplus
set()
```